# Python in CorelDraw

Tags: python, language-agnostic, cross-platform, coreldraw

I was looking for most cross platform (& easy) programming language to learn,
I thought it is Python specially after some investigations, all paths I look in I found Python can be an option to develop it (Ubuntu desktop etc.), but when it comes to CorelDraw (VBA) I didn't found Python can do it, so here is my question.

Is there a way to develop/automate CorelDraw in Python?

I don't want just a scripting option like javaScript also of course don't want any option like C,C++ other wise I would say Assembly :)

Also HTML5 is not the solution, as I am looking for back end (unless I am missing some information about HTML5)

Also let me give examples of what I want to be able to do (every thing)
1. Windows application (all versions, specially new 7,8)
2. Web
3. class Lib
4. skype add-on
5. Replace VBA (Excel VBA, Corel VBA)
6. build ubuntu deskTop app
7. Build mobile application (iPhone, andRoid & of course Ubuntu)
8. Chrome application/add-on
9. FireFox add-on
10 ... etc.
Thanx,

Comment: Corel Paint Shop Pro can run Python scripts.

Comment: any link or more info please, so you mean Corel Paint Shop Pro but not CorelDraw?

Comment: Actually I meant CorelDraw not Corel Paint Shop Pro

Comment: I was simply pointing out an alternative. I'm sorry it wasn't helpful to you.

Comment: Commercial solutions are mostly not scalable and flexible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not worked on graphics designing packages; but i know that CorelDraw is not cross-platform. It is windows specific. But you have mentioned that your need is cross-platform; so you have to change your choice of app on which you will be working. 
For that; There are three very famous cross-platform apps are out there; [`Inkscape`](http://www.inkscape.org/), [`GIMP`](http://www.gimp.org/docs/python/index.html) and [`Blender`](http://www.blender.org/education-help/python/). Also;all supports python scripting.

Example tutorial of inkscape: http://oco-carbon.com/2012/05/13/heat-maps-with-python-and-inkscape/

Comment: Thank you but, I know CorelDraw is not cross plat form, when I say cross platform, I mean the programming language not corel

Comment: You are right; but here app has to be in first place; ultimately you will be working in that.
In such eco-system; apps with cross-platform ability will adopt similar requirements(Python/C/C++ in their core); its a natural selection.. ."app" and its "language" both are important.If you are selecting language(/or app) other will come automatically with it. 
(otherwise you have to write everything again according to your choice/requirement; and it will even take a decade to reach the levels of maturity)
anyway; lets see what others are saying...